# How to apply a function that affects the parent of each element with a certain class name?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of `div`s with the class name `x` that are inside of other `div`s with the class name `item`. The `item` `div`s are inside a section of the main.

What I want to do is create a function that applies equally to every `x` class `div` by affecting their respective parent (in this case changing their CSS).

I coded this:

```
var openbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0];
openbtn.onclick = function() {
    document.body.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

However, this only works on the first `x` class `<div>`. When it works, it changes the background color of the section, or main or body element, and not the `x` class `div` parent (the `item` class div).

Comment: To affect the button's parent, you need to replace `document.body` with `this`. Here's one I wrote today for a very similar question: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3wLtav24/

Comment: can you share your HTML DOM structure?

Comment: Based on your explanation, it sounds like employing event delegation technique could be pretty helpful to you  (as TJ's answer below explains) - adding a single event listener on a parent element is more efficient than looping over each individual `div` and applying a distinct event listener for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle this with a handler on each `.x` element, you have to add a handler to each `.x` element. (But you may not want to do that, keep reading.) That would look like this:

```
var openbtns = document.getElementsByClassName("x");
for (var n = 0; n < openbtns.length; ++n) {
    openbtns[n].addEventListener("click", xClickHandler);
}
```

...where `xClickHandler` uses `this` (or `event.currentTarget`) to know which `.x` element was clicked:

```
function xClickHandler() {
    this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // I suggest using a class instead of doing this, btw
}
```

**But**, if all of these `.x` elements are within the same overall container, you can do it with *event delegation*, like this:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-the-overall-container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Find the `.x` that was clicked (which may be `event.target` or may be
    // an ancestor node of it
    var x = event.target.closest(".x");
    if (x && this.contains(x)) {
        x.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Again, suggest using a class
    }
});
```

More:

- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

Live Example using the HTML from your comment:

```js
document.getElementById("items").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Find the `.x` that was clicked (which may be `event.target` or may be
    // an ancestor node of it
    var x = event.target.closest(".x");
    if (x && this.contains(x)) {
        x.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Again, suggest using a class
    }
});
```

```css
.x {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
section {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<main id="items">
  <section id="design">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="x"></div>
      <h1>Design stuff</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="art">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Art stuff</h1>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Well I used the first method you metioned and it worked except in one thing.

The 'click function' targets not the parent, but the grandparent of the class 'div' (i dont know why). Let me show you me HTML structure.

Comment: <main id="items">
            <section id="design">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="x"></div>
                    <h1>Design stuff</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="art">
                <div class="item">
                    <h1>Art stuff</h1>
                    <div class="x"></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>

i tried to format the text properly but idk why, it dosent want to

Comment: `<main id="items">
            <section id="design">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="x"></div>
                    <h1>Design stuff</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="art">
                <div class="item">
                    <h1>Art stuff</h1>
                    <div class="x"></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>`

instead of targeting the 'div class "item"' it targets the 'section'

Comment: @godofthunder - No reason it should do that, and it doesn't in the live example I just added using that markup.

Comment: well it problably is something in my code, i'll review it

Comment: fthank you so much! the problem was that I had a background-image in the form of a color (blue) that prevented me from seeing the transformation.

Now i only have one question left, what do you mean by using a class to change the css of the element? (which in this case was hte background color)

Comment: @godofthunder - Instead of directly setting `.style.backgroundColor`, I'd use `.classList.add("some-class")` and define the color in the CSS for `.some-class`.

Comment: awesome advice!!! to my purposes it was best aplied a toggling function between classes, but your advice enlightned what I wanted to do and how I would do it
thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listener to each element using a for of loop:

```js
var openbtnList = document.getElementsByClassName("x");

for (let x of openbtnList) {
  x.addEventListener("click", clickX, false);
};

function clickX() {
  this.parentElement.classList.toggle("red"); // sstyle.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.item::before {
  content: " ";
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/80/100) center/cover;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.x::before {
  content: "X";
  color: white;
  font: 30px/30px sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.red {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

---